# How to record the output of audio card in 10 second chunks?

Tags: windows, audio, audio-recording, audacity

I want to record the output of my sound card.  I understand that there are options (e.g. Stereo Mix with Audacity, Virtual Audio Cable, etc...).

However, I want to record it in 10 second chunks (or some other arbitrary interval).  In other words, file1.mp3 should be 10 seconds long.  Then file2.mp3 should start immediately after file1.mp3 and last 10 seconds as well and so on.

Is there any way to do that?

Comment: Why not record one long chunk and then split the file later?

Comment: @DavidPostill Because the recording is for a week...the file would be huge

Comment: If you record in 10 second chunks you will lose data between the chunks.

Comment: @DavidPostill What would you suggest as my solution then?

Comment: I've no idea. It looks like an XY problem .[What is the XY problem?](http://meta.stackexchange.com/a/66378)

Comment: @DavidPostill A solution might be to record it in 1 hour chunks..and then split it into 10s pieces.  I don't mind loosing a bit on an hourly basis. 

However, I still haven't found how to record it in chunks.